# Elementor header and footer disappear after activating WPML plugin

Tags: wordpress, elementor, wpml

everyone.
I installed and activated WPML plugin for multi-language.
But after activating it, my elementor header and footer disappeard.
I tried to find the solution.
The blogs say that it is due to compatibility issue.
So I should remove all plugins and install one by one.
Can't I fix this issue without removing plugins?

Comment: The blogs likely don't say to "remove" plugins - try deactivating them first. The idea is to narrow down the problem. Also don't forget to update Elementor itself as well as WordPress core. Make a backup before you do anything.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Of course, I deactivated the plugins. But the issue wasn't resolved.

Comment: Hard to say what it is. Check for any [JavaScript errors](https://wordpress.org/support/article/using-your-browser-to-diagnose-javascript-errors/#step-3-diagnosis) when using Elementor, then [enable debugging](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/) and check for PHP errors. Create a new footer when WPML is active, test it out and translate.

Comment: Same here, activating WPML String Translation makes my header disappear in all languages.

Answer (score 1):

The original question was year ago, but for the other people faced the issue:

1. You can try to **re-save the conditions for the Header and Footer in the Elementor Theme Builder section**, it should resolve the issue.
2. Also there's the similar (currently, opened) issue on the Github which may help: https://github.com/elementor/elementor/issues/15306

They suggest to change the plugin's code:
https://wpml.org/errata/elementor-pro-template-display-conditions-does-not-work-with-multiple-languages/

Please be awared, **changing plugin's code is a terrible practice**, but it's just a one line of code which could prevent the issue, at least before the plugin's update.

Comment: for it is not anymore displayed in the elementor header and footer section i saw number but when i click nothing appear